# Failed to convert parameter value from a string to int64

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm getting an error : Failed to convert parameter from string to Int 64
here is the ligne :

```
com.Parameters.Add("@NBC", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = ligneGridBC1.Cells["NBcmd"].ToString();
```

I already  tried

```
com.Parameters.Add("@NBC", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = Convert.ToInt64(ligneGridBC1.Cells["NBcmd"].ToString());

com.Parameters.Add("@NBC", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = Int64.Parse(ligneGridBC1.Cells["NBcmd"].ToString());
```

My sql table contains 
`NBC BigInt`
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the value of `ligneGridBC1.Cells["NBcmd"].ToString()`?

Comment: Convert.ToInt64(ligneGridBC1.Cells["NBcmd"]);

Comment: Check whether ligneGridBC1.Cells["NBcmd"] returns empty string, if return empty then this error will occurr. Try to keep default value as 0 if the cell value is either null or empty.

Answer (score 0):

What type of object does ligneGridDC1.Cells["NBcmd"] contain?

Calling .ToString() on an object will by default return the type of object, unless the ToString method has been overridden. you're trying to convert 'SomeType.Cell' to a Int64.

Try this...

```
        Int64 a = 0;
        if(!Int64.TryParse(ligneGridBC1.Cells["NBcmd"].ToString(), out a))
            throw new InvalidCastException(ligneGridBC1.Cells["NBcmd"].ToString());
        com.Parameters.Add("@NBC", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = a;
```

Hope that helps